# How to Find Minimum Value in Excel 2010 and compare it with Another cell value and return index of lowest value

Tags: excel, min

[image: Sample Data]

I would like to compare Parameters( P1,P2,P3 & P4) find minimum value out of these which would be min(b:e), then compare the minimum obtained number with the number in my reference box, if its same result should return Index of Refrence number (which is "Reference") else return index of the minimum value. If the Min of P1, p2 p3 & p4 is greater than Refrence number result should be index of Refrence number.

Comment: Sorry but I did not follow. So from your data above, what would be the result?

Comment: I want my result show name of lowest value colums ex Refrence or P1 or P2 anything that is lowest, i have used formula =INDEX(E$1:I$1,MATCH(MIN(E3:I3),E3:I3,0)), where reference sits in E column and P1 p2 p3 respectively in F, G H And I but i get error when lowest value is same as reference value, it shows lowest value is refrence value however lowest value should then be considered between p1,p2,p3 and p4

Comment: I've edited your question. Does your data look like that? If yes, what data do you expect on `Result` under `Column J`?

Comment: Thanks so much for editing it to show correct format, and showing interst in my question. Under Result Column i need it to give me name of lowest value column. For first row all 4 numbers are same as Reference number hence resut to say "Reference" For secong row lowest number is 2 amongst p1, p2, p3 and p4 however it is also the same as my reference number, my formula gives result as "Reference" however i want it to be P3. And For row 3 it should be p3 again.

Comment: If all the values are same i would want result to show "Reference"

Comment: Regardless if it is not equal to `Reference` as long as it's the same the result would be `Reference`?

Comment: Yes, Refrence should be displayed when its minimum value or all the values are same. But if reference value and minimum value is same and other values are diffrent then i want the index of that minimum value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(E$1:I$1,1,IF(SUM(IF(E2=F2:I2,1,0))=4,1,MATCH(MIN(F2:I2),F2:I2,0)+1))
```

Entered as array formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in `Cell J2`
It should look like this:

[image: Sample Result]

Then just copy it to the remaining cells.
Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank You so much, you just saved my hours and hours

Comment: Cool! No problem. Try reading [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) if you have time to help you get a hang of `Array Formulas`. It is a good read.